# plot a tube via a 4D plot

Tags: plotting

I have a function

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-z^2]
```

which traces out a tube along $y$. Is there a way to plot this 4D function, where the plot color is the 4th dimension?

Comment: I should have checked earlier: Duplicate: [1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/visualize-plot-of-a-function-of-3-variables-using-color-and-contours) and a couple of related ones: [2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/plot-4d-data-with-color-as-4th-dimension), [3)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/what-are-the-possible-ways-of-visualizing-a-4d-function-in-mathematica)

Comment: @MichaelE2 those weren't very tube-y, though, which I thought was the intention behind the Q.

Comment: @cormullion I think they are very tube-y but not `Tube`-y, since circular cylinders are tubes.  I was confused at first whether "tube" meant `Tube[..]`, but later I realized the contours were cylinders whose axis was the y-axis, just as in the Q.  (Frankly, `f` does not trace out tubes and "the 4th dimension" is unclear. The function is not a parametrization, and "the 4th dimension" makes sense to me only if the Q is referring to the graph of `f`, which is a 3D hypersurface in R^4.  I think one has to guess at the meaning of the Q as it is stated.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is `ContourPlot3D`.  There are two ways to color the contours.

`ColorFunction` has a certain attractive automatic feature to it, but it doesn't color as nicely as `ContourStyle`, especially if you are coloring the surfaces by the function value.  `ContourStyle` produces smaller graphics and is faster, too.

```
cons = {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8};
ContourPlot3D[
 Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-z^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None,
 Contours -> cons, ContourStyle -> Hue /@ cons]
```

[image: ContourStyle]

```
ContourPlot3D[Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-z^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, Hue[f]]]
```

[image: ColorFunction]

You can also diminish the `Opacity` of the contours; see the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You can vary the color of the tube as it goes along - if you provide a list of the colours that it passes through to `VertexColors`:

```
Graphics3D[
 {CapForm["Round"],
  Tube[
   Accumulate[
    RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {50, 3}]], .3, 
   VertexColors -> 
    Table[RGBColor[x, 1 - x, 0.5 - x/2], {x, 0, 1, 1/50}]]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Background -> Gray,
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: its quicker by tube]

Answer (score 1):

Have I understood correctly? Look at this:

Edit: I forgot `ColorFunctionScaling`. Now it is ok.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -12, 12}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][Exp[-x^2]*Exp[-z^2]]]]
```

[image]