# Coloring a shape according to a function

Tags: graphics, color

I would like to create a $2D$ shape, say an ellipse, where each point in the ellipse is colored according a `RGB` function, so at point `x` and `y` the color would be:

```
RGBColor[ u[x,y], v[x,y], w[x,y]]
```

I am sure there has to be an easy way to do this, but I have not had much luck.

Comment: Look up `ParametricPlot[]`.

Comment: This might help, the answer achieves a similar effect (in 3D).  Also, it links to other, similar questions in the comments of the question.

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26636/plot-a-tube-via-a-4d-plot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
u[x_, y_] := Sin[x] + Cos[y]
v[x_, y_] := E^-x + y
w[x_, y_] := Tanh[x] + Sqrt[y]
RegionPlot[2 x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None,
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[u[x, y], v[x, y], w[x, y]]]]
```

Result: [image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Let's use a polar formula for a conic curve,

```
cc[u_, eps_] := {1/(1 + eps Cos[u]) Cos[u], 1/(1 + eps Cos[u]) Sin[u]}
```

For `-1 < eps < 1` we have an ellipse, for `eps == 1` a parabola, and for `eps > 1` a hyperbola.

We assume a simple function to describe dependence of the color on the angle:

```
ParametricPlot[ cc[u, 2/3], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, Hue[u/(2 Pi)]], 
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: colored ellipse]

```
ParametricPlot[ cc[u, 1], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, Hue[u/(2 Pi)]], 
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

and to plot a hyperbola we'd use `Exclusions` (to get rid of zero from the denominator) e.g.

```
ParametricPlot[ cc[u, 3/2], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
                ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, Hue[u/(2 Pi)]], 
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Exclusions -> {Cos[u] == 2/3, Cos[u] == -2/3}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get to see the polar (Keplerian) form everyday, so +1 for that. :)