# How can I plot a hyperbola from its complex representation?

Tags: plotting, complex

How can I plot the hyperbola represented by the following complex equation:

$$\left|z-a\right|-\left|z-b\right|=2t\tag{1}$$

Should I convert (1) into the following form?

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: contour plot of hyperbola]

Comment: You can start from `ComplexExpand[Abs[x + I y - a] - Abs[x + I y - b], 
 TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`, which doe not give an hyperbola though.

Comment: Are you sure the complex expression above is a hyperbola? What do the $a, b, t$ stand for? Assuming that the $a$ and $b$ are the same as in $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$, then that is not a hyperbola. For instance, what happens when $a=b$?

Comment: You can the function defined here: [Coloring a shape according to a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function/26900#26900), e.g. `ParametricPlot[cc[u, 3/2], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thick, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, Hue[u/(2 Pi)]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Exclusions -> {Cos[u] == 2/3, Cos[u] == -2/3}]`

Answer (score 7):

Since you're trying to plot an implicit equation, you would normally use `ContourPlot`. For example, to get two branches satisfying the equation for $t = 1$,  just do this:

```
With[{a = 2, b = 1},
 ContourPlot[
  Abs[x + I y - a] - Abs[x + I y - b], {x, -1, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Contours -> {1/2, -1/2}, ContourShading -> False, 
  ContourStyle -> ColorData[1][1]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: contours]