# how to plot and animate an hyperbole?

Tags: plotting

I am an new user of *Mathematica* and learning basics so please guide me

I tried to use this code

```
Animate[Plot[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}], 
  {a, 1, 3}, 
  {b, 1, 3}]
```

but I got this error message:

> Plot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {y,0,2}) beyond position 3 in Plot[x^2/FE`a$$116^2-y^2/FE`b$$116^2==1,{x,0,2},{y,0,2}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules. >>

All I want to do is to animate a hyperbole with its asymptotes.

Comment: @ b.gatessucks i don't know that .
if you know ,just write the answer

Comment: Hi Hash. Functions are case-sensitive, and Plot only takes one variable. Try to get a Plot first, then animate it?

Comment: Related: [Coloring a shape according to a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function/26900#26900)

Comment: If it's animated hyperbole you are after, maybe use conspiracy plots. Or perhaps `CounterPlot`. (Sorry, it's Friday..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Animate[ContourPlot[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

OR

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

If you want the plots with the asymptotes, use the following:

```
Animate[ContourPlot[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, a y + b x == 0, 
   a y - b x == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

OR

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[{x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 == 1, a y + b x == 0, 
   a y - b x == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: is it possible to generate hyperbole along with its asymptotes

Comment: @Hash. Yes. See my edit

Comment: Maybe you need `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` in `ContourPlot`

Comment: @chyanog. Good call. Added it. Thanks.

Comment: so Quality is also a in-built function in mathematica and now the hyperbole looks nice