# Plotting 2D color function on the plane

Tags: plotting, color

Suppose `p` is a some point in the plane. The function `f[q]` defined as

```
f[q_]:= Block[{d = Norm[p-q]}, RGBColor[1 - d/(1 + d), 0, d/(1 + d)]]
```

Continuously colors points in the plane by thier distance from `p`. What is the easiest way to plot this in 2D? I tried DensityPlot but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Basically I want to specify some color function for points in the plane and plot it. Contours would be a bonus.

Apologies if this exact question has been asked before.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this [Coloring a shape according to a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function/26900#26900).

Comment: Yes. I think that will work. RegionPlot looks like the solution. Mebbe I should delete this question.

Comment: OK I can't get this to work for a simple example. 
I put `p = {2,3}`, `f` as above, then

`RegionPlot[True, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, f@{x, y}]]`

Doesn't work, gives a solid square.

Comment: Add `ColorFunctionScaling->False` to your plot and see if that does what you'd like.

Comment: That did it, thaks @bobthechemist!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun, try this

```
ControllerManipulate[
 RegionPlot[True, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y}, 
    Block[{d = Norm[l - #]}, 
       RGBColor[1 - d/(1 + d), 0, d/(1 + d)]] & @{x, y}]], {{l, {2, 
    2}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]