# Plotting a Partially Filled Ellipse

Tags: geometry

I would like to plot a partially filled/shaded ellipse. The code below shades the whole ellipse. However, I only want to shade the part of the ellipse to the right of the vertical line where x > cutscore.

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

cutscore = 0.5; 
data1 = RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0.6}, {0.6, 1}}], 500];
ellipse1 = EllipsoidQuantile[data1, 0.5];
e1 = Graphics[ellipse1];
line1 = Graphics[{Line[{{cutscore, -1.3}, {0.5, 1.5}}]}];
show1SEL = Show[e1, line1, Axes -> {True, False}, AxesOrigin -> {-2, -2}, 
           PlotRange -> {{-2, Automatic}, {-2, Automatic}}];
show1SELfilled = show1SEL /. Line[x_] -> {Green, EdgeForm@Thin, FaceForm[Opacity@.2], Polygon[x]}
```

Comment: You haven't defined `EllipsoidQuantile`. This is related: [Coloring a shape according to a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function).

Comment: `EllipsoidQuantile` is defined in ``"MultivariateStatistics`"``, now added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Needs["MultivariateStatistics`"]

cutscore = 0.5;
data1 =
  RandomVariate[
   MultinormalDistribution[
    {0, 0}, {{1, 0.6}, {0.6, 1}}],
   500];
ellipse1 = EllipsoidQuantile[data1, 0.5];
e1 = Graphics[ellipse1];
line1 = Graphics[{
    Line[{{cutscore, -1.3}, {cutscore, 1.5}}]}];

show1SELfilled = Show[e1, line1,
  Graphics[{
    LightBlue,
    Polygon[
     DeleteCases[
      Cases[e1, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity][[1]],
      {_?(# < cutscore &), _}]]}],
  Axes -> {True, False},
  AxesOrigin -> {-1.5, -1.5},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, Automatic}, {-1.5, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob, This is exactly what I needed - Dan Segall