# How do I create plots of rotated conic sections?

Tags: plotting

*Mathematica* works well with many kind of plots, but I cant figure out how to plot conic sections with rotated axis. For example "plot $y = (3x + \sqrt{x(16-7x)})/4, y = (3x - \sqrt{x(16-7x)})/4$" will not give me an ellipse, but gives me a zigzag mix of real and imaginary parts lines. How do I get rotated conic? Can you provide examples of hyperbola and parabola also?

Here a stub to meet demands of code formatting

```
Plot[y /. Solve[y == (3 x + sqrt (x (16 - 7 x)))/4], {x, -20, 20}]
```

Comment: Your code isn't useable as is, try to copy it directly from your notebook (I assume you would see the error with `sqrt` instead of `Sqrt`).  Also, your `Solve` isn't formatted correctly, you already have it solved for `y`.

Comment: I recommend to play around with parametric representations of [conic sections](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/coloring-a-shape-according-to-a-function/26900#26900)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ellipse plots pretty easily if you get the syntax right.

```
Plot[{(3 x + Sqrt[x (16 - 7 x)])/4, (3 x - Sqrt[x (16 - 7 x)])/4}, {x, 0, 2.5}]
```

[image: plot]