# spherical polar plot of radial function

Tags: plotting

Can you please tell me how to plot $\sqrt{r}$ in 3d sph polar plot?

In the spherical plot 3d there is no option I can put  variable r. So how should I proceed.

Comment: So you want $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ function? In exactly this case maybe better just `Plot[Sqrt[r],{r, 0, rmax}]`. In more complicated example, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/5478

Comment: @Kuba yes. actually I have to draw $|\bar{x}|^\frac{1}{2}$ where $\bar{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3$ i.e $\bar{x}=(x,y,z)$.

Comment: To plot $\sqrt{r}$ vs. $(x,y,z)$, you would need four coordinates.  See for example these questions: [19575](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19575/), [20023](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20023/), [25277](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25277/), [26636](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26636/plot-a-tube-via-a-4d-plot)  - (Oh, Kuba beat to the first one while I was searching. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 About that link, shouldn't the title be corrected to "3D functions", I mean, th "n" in "n-D functions" usualy reffers to dimension of a domain, doesn't it?

Comment: To MichaelE2 and Kuba Please correct me if I have mistakes. I need the plot in 3D. Please see this notes on sobolev space (pg 21, Fig 2.2)where I encountered this http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~munnier/files/cours_edp.pdf  I want to reproduce the plot and I got the problem. Thanking you both once again.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, that would be correct, from a mathematician's point of view.  Often others refer to the dimension of the embedding, e.g. a 3D curve meaning a 1D object in ${\Bbb R}^3$. The standard embedding of the graph of a real-valued function $(x, f(x))$ takes $n+1$ coordinates, if $x \in {\Bbb R}^n$.  Calling it 4D actually helped me find the question, so I don't object to the loose use of the terminology.

Comment: @ricci1729 The figure is for $u :{\Bbb R}^2 \rightarrow {\Bbb R}$, for which you can use `RevolutionPlot3D`.

Comment: Just to make @MichaelE2 's suggestion explicit, you could do `RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[r], {r, 0, 1}]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Sqrt@Sqrt[ u u + v v]}, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2},
                RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#4, #5}] < 1 &), AspectRatio -> 1, 
                MeshFunctions -> {(#3 &), (ArcTan[#2, #1] &)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare with your book:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: if you want to avoid this real nuisance indeterminacy message you may replace ArcTan with (Arg[Complex[#2, #1]] &)

Comment: @Stefan Or just enclose the whole thing in `Quiet[]` :)